# Alignments in bussproofs package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, logic

I'm using [`bussproofs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bussproofs) and would like my premises always to be left-aligned with the beginning of the inference line. So far when I have a single premise inference, I can only get the premise centered on the inference line, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree} \AxiomC{$\neg A$} \UnaryInfC{$\neg A \lor \neg B$} \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to get the premise be left aligned with the line?

Comment: What I meant is that normally I get something like this:     \begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\neg A$}
 \UnaryInfC{$\neg A \lor \neg B$}

 \end{prooftree} Now, what I would like to achieve is that when I have a single premise argument, that my premise stand at the left-most side of the inference line, and not in the center as it is now.

Comment: Sorry, but we need a minimal example that includes also the call to the necessary packages. You can edit your question, in order to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options:

1. Set the smaller box (your premise `\AxiomC`) in a box of the same width as the larger box (your conclusion `\UnaryInfC`), only left-aligned. This can be achieved using `\makebox[<width>][l]{...}`; or
2. Use `\phantom{<stuff>}` to remove `<stuff>` from the display but still have the appropriate space allocated for it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bussproofs
\newlength{\mylen}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  \settowidth{\mylen}{$\neg A \lor \neg B$}%
  \AxiomC{\makebox[\mylen][l]{$\neg A$}}
  \UnaryInfC{$\neg A \lor \neg B$}
\end{prooftree}

\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{$\neg A \phantom{\:{\lor}\:\neg B}$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\neg A \lor \neg B$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

In the first example, the width of the conclusion is stored in `\mylen` (a new length) via `\settowidth`. `\mylen` is then used to provide the box width for the premise.

In the second example, a minor correction for the spacing around the binary operator `\lor` is performed by adding `\:` around the now atomized `{\lor}`.

Answer (score 4):

This is doable by default in bussproof (rtfm: section 3) using sequent-aligned style, the commands are the same wihout the final "C", they do not take brackets around their argument and the `\fCenter` command marks the point of alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
   \Axiom$\fCenter\neg A$
   \UnaryInf$\fCenter\neg A \lor \neg B$
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\kernHyps{kern}` before the inference command to nudge the hypothesis of that inference by the distance of *kern*. e.g. .1in or -.1in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree} \AxiomC{$\kernHyps{-.18in}\neg A$} \UnaryInfC{$\neg A \lor \neg B$} \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

This will give you

[image]